# Drupal 6 next tid value

Tags: drupal-6

I need to find the next tid value that will be created when I create a new term. The term_data table does not show this value as the term with the highest tid can be deleted. It looks like the sequences table held this value in Drupal 5 but where is it held in Drupal 6?

Thanks for your time with this!

Answer (score 0):

What do you need this for? You should be creating the term, then pulling the ID based on the vocabulary ID plus the term, like this -

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('whatever the term is');
$new_term_id = $term->tid;
```

But to answer your question specifically -

```
$result = db_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'term_data'");
$row = db_fetch_array($result);
$next_id = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Comment: I am using hook_form_alter to add a field to the add/edit term form. Now, any data I add in here does not get saved so I created a new table and saved the data there. This worked fine when editing terms but when create a new term the tid has not been created yet, thus why I was looking for the next tid. Not sure if this is the best approach but I'm giving it a go.

Comment: You're welcome. You should always remember to accept answers if you're going to hang around!